# Prometheus: cannot export metrics from connected Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

The issue: I have a Prometheus outside of Kubernetes cluster. So, I want to export metrics from remote cluster.

I took the config sample from [Prometheus Github repo](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml) and modified this a little bit. So, here is my jobs config.

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'

    scheme: http

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      api_server: http://cluster-manager.dev.example.net:8080

    bearer_token_file: /opt/prometheus/prometheus/kube_tokens/dev
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
      action: keep
      regex: default;kubernetes;http

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'

    scheme: http

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: node
      api_server: http://cluster-manager.dev.example.net:8080

    bearer_token_file: /opt/prometheus/prometheus/kube_tokens/dev
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

    relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

    scheme: http

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      api_server: http://cluster-manager.dev.example.net:8080

    bearer_token_file: /opt/prometheus/prometheus/kube_tokens/dev
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
      action: replace
      target_label: __scheme__
      regex: (http?)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      target_label: __address__
      regex: (.+)(?::\d+);(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_name

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-services'

    scheme: http

    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: service
      api_server: http://cluster-manager.dev.example.net:8080

    bearer_token_file: /opt/prometheus/prometheus/kube_tokens/dev
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: blackbox
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_namespace]
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
      target_label: kubernetes_name

  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

    scheme: http

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod
      api_server: http://cluster-manager.dev.example.net:8080

    bearer_token_file: /opt/prometheus/prometheus/kube_tokens/dev
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      regex: (.+):(?:\d+);(\d+)
      replacement: ${1}:${2}
      target_label: __address__
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

I don't use a TLS connection to API, so I want to disable it.

When I curl `/metrics` URL from Prometheus host - it prints them.

Finally I connected to the cluster, but...the jobs are not up and therefore Prometheus doesn't expose relabeled metrics.

What I see in Console.

[image]

[image]

Targets state:

[image]

Also I checked the Prometheus debug. It's thought the system gets any necessary information and requests are done successfully.

```
time="2017-01-25T06:58:04Z" level=debug msg="pod update" kubernetes_sd=pod source="pod.go:66" tg="&config.TargetGroup{Targets:[]model.LabelSet{model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"UDP\", \"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:10053\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"kube-dns\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"10053\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"dns-local\"}, model.LabelSet{\"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:10053\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"kube-dns\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"10053\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"dns-tcp-local\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"TCP\"}, model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"kube-dns\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"10055\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"metrics\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"TCP\", \"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:10055\"}, model.LabelSet{\"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:53\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"dnsmasq\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"53\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"dns\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"UDP\"}, model.LabelSet{\"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:53\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"dnsmasq\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"53\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"dns-tcp\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"TCP\"}, model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"10054\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"metrics\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"TCP\", \"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:10054\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"dnsmasq-metrics\"}, model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_protocol\":\"TCP\", \"__address__\":\"10.32.0.2:8080\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"healthz\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number\":\"8080\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name\":\"\"}}, Labels:model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_pod_ready\":\"true\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_kubernetes_io_created_by\":\"{\\\"kind\\\":\\\"SerializedReference\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"v1\\\",\\\"reference\\\":{\\\"kind\\\":\\\"ReplicaSet\\\",\\\"namespace\\\":\\\"kube-system\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"kube-dns-2924299975\\\",\\\"uid\\\":\\\"fa808d95-d7d9-11e6-9ac9-02dfdae1a1e9\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"extensions\\\",\\\"resourceVersion\\\":\\\"89\\\"}}\\n\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_scheduler_alpha_kubernetes_io_affinity\":\"{\\\"nodeAffinity\\\":{\\\"requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution\\\":{\\\"nodeSelectorTerms\\\":[{\\\"matchExpressions\\\":[{\\\"key\\\":\\\"beta.kubernetes.io/arch\\\",\\\"operator\\\":\\\"In\\\",\\\"values\\\":[\\\"amd64\\\"]}]}]}}}\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_name\":\"kube-dns-2924299975-dksg5\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_ip\":\"10.32.0.2\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_k8s_app\":\"kube-dns\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_pod_template_hash\":\"2924299975\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_tier\":\"node\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_scheduler_alpha_kubernetes_io_tolerations\":\"[{\\\"key\\\":\\\"dedicated\\\",\\\"value\\\":\\\"master\\\",\\\"effect\\\":\\\"NoSchedule\\\"}]\", \"__meta_kubernetes_namespace\":\"kube-system\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name\":\"cluster-manager.dev.example.net\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_component\":\"kube-dns\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_kubernetes_io_cluster_service\":\"true\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip\":\"54.194.166.39\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_name\":\"kube-dns\"}, Source:\"pod/kube-system/kube-dns-2924299975-dksg5\"}" 
time="2017-01-25T06:58:04Z" level=debug msg="pod update" kubernetes_sd=pod source="pod.go:66" tg="&config.TargetGroup{Targets:[]model.LabelSet{model.LabelSet{\"__address__\":\"10.43.0.0\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name\":\"bot\"}}, Labels:model.LabelSet{\"__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip\":\"172.17.101.25\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_app\":\"bot\", \"__meta_kubernetes_namespace\":\"default\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_name\":\"bot-272181271-pnzsz\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_ip\":\"10.43.0.0\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name\":\"ip-172-17-101-25\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_kubernetes_io_created_by\":\"{\\\"kind\\\":\\\"SerializedReference\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"v1\\\",\\\"reference\\\":{\\\"kind\\\":\\\"ReplicaSet\\\",\\\"namespace\\\":\\\"default\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"bot-272181271\\\",\\\"uid\\\":\\\"c297b3c2-e15d-11e6-a28a-02dfdae1a1e9\\\",\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"extensions\\\",\\\"resourceVersion\\\":\\\"1465127\\\"}}\\n\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_ready\":\"true\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_pod_template_hash\":\"272181271\", \"__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_version\":\"v0.1\"}, Source:\"pod/default/bot-272181271-pnzsz\"}"
```

Prometheus fetches updates, but...doesn't convert them to metrics.
So, I've broken my brain to figure out why is it going this way. So, please, help if you can figure out where might be mistake.

Comment: can you post an image of your status->target pages from the ui?

Comment: Updated. So strange that I see only one Kubernetes jobs from all pointed in config.

Comment: I dont have any experience with Kubernetes, but if Prometheus says they're down its likely it can't reach them. if you curl those ips from the host that prometheus is installed on, do you get the metrics? (probably on port 9090)

Comment: Oh, actually I can reach only one, external, because my Prometheus node is out of cluster. But how can I monitor another nodes if they're not in my local network? Just trying to rewrite the target address?
Anyway thanks for the great prompt. Now I at least know where is the issue.

Comment: As I mentioned I have no experience with Kubernetes but perhaps you could modify the IPs it exposes to Prometheus, although rewriting the target address would also work. 

We have a consul-based setup and indeed had to resort to rewriting the ports @ Prometheus.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to monitor a Kubernetes cluster from an external Prometheus server, I would suggest to set up a [Prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/#use-cases) topology:

- Inside the K8s, install node-exporter pods and a Prometheus instance with short-term storage.
- Expose the Prometheus service out of the K8s cluster, either via an ingress-controller (LB), or a node port. You can protect this endpoint with HTTPS + basic authentication.
- Configure the center Prometheus to scrape metrics from above endpoint with proper authentication and tags.

This is the scalable solution. You can add monitor as many K8s clusters you want, until it reaches the capacities of the center Prometheus. Then you can add another center Prometheus instance to monitor others.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I came to the though it's not trivial to setup Kubernetes cluster monitoring outside of cluster. Cause Kubernetes architecture suggested to keep all infrastructure within one local network. So, every workaround is going to be messy.
Also I came to the problem trying to debug why all configured jobs about Kubernetes roles such as nods, pods, services and endpoints doensn't even show up in targets status page. I may think wrong, but I didn't find out how to debug this issue in Prometheus.

My solution to monitor Kubernetes cluster outside was a [kube-api-exporter](https://github.com/tomwilkie/kube-api-exporter). Pretty simple Python script which gets all metrics about ds, deployments and pods and finally provides the URL to fetch them. So, I'd recommend to come to this solution everyone who's got stuck with this sort of integration.

Also I started to fetch metrics from etcd. That's cool that etcd provides Prometheus-style metrics out of the box.

P.S.: thanks to [FuzzyAmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277048/fuzzyami) for help.

Comment: Are there any additional changes required on the central Prometheus server? I am trying to do a similar POC but unable to find a good article to achieve it.