# Prometheus kuberentes-pods Get "https:// xx.xx.xx:443 /metrics": dial tcp xx.xx.xx:443: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-pod

I have configured Prometheus on one of the kubernetes cluster nodes using [this][1].  After that I added following `prometheus.yml` file. I can list nodes and apiservers but for pods, all the pods shows down and error:

```
Get "https:// xx.xx.xx:443 /metrics": dial tcp xx.xx.xx:443: connect: connection refused and for some pods the status is unknown.
```

Can someone point me what am I doing wrong here?

```
Cat prometheus.yml



global:
  scrape_interval: 1m
 
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: \['localhost:9090'\]
 
# metrics for default/kubernetes api's from the kubernetes master
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod
      bearer_token_file: /dfgdjk/token
      api_server: https://masterapi.com:3343
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /dfgdjk/token
    scheme: https
    relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: \[__meta_kubernetes_namespace\]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: \[__meta_kubernetes_pod_name\]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
 
# metrics for default/kubernetes api's from the kubernetes master
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      api_server: https://masterapi.com:3343
      bearer_token_file: /dfgdjk/token
      tls_config:
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /dfgdjk/token
    scheme: https
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: \[__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name\]
      action: keep
      regex: default;kubernetes;https][1]
 


  [1]: https://devopscube.com/install-configure-prometheus-linux/
```

Comment: Welcome to the community! I can see you're following a article about setting up prometheus on `linux` host while you actually should focus on doing it for kubernetes. E.g. the same website [has dedicated article for kubernetes](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/). If still no luck. please share the steps you did and where you think you're stuck.

Comment: My management doesn’t want Prometheus to run in k8, for that reason I installed on a Linux server. I can able to list nodes but for metrics for each pod with ip’s error out with connection refused

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to get metrics to external prometheus server without having any prometheus components inside the kubernetes cluster. This happens because cluster network is isolated with host's network and it's not possible to scrape metrics from pods directly from outside the cluster.

Please refer to [Monitoring kubernetes with prometheus from outside of k8s cluster GitHub issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/4633)

There options which can be done:

- install prometheus inside the cluster using `prometheus operator` or manually - [example](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-monitoring-prometheus/#install)
- use proxy solutions, for example this one from the same thread on GitHub - [k8s-prometheus-proxy](https://github.com/americanexpress/k8s-prometheus-proxy)
- on top of the prometheus installed within the cluster, it's possible to have external prometheus in `federation` so all logs are saved outside of the cluster. Please refer to [prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).

Also important part is [kube state metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) should be installed as well in kubernetes cluster. [How to set it up](https://devopscube.com/setup-kube-state-metrics/).

**Edit:** also you can refer to [another SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41845307) which confirms that only with additional steps or OP resolved it by another proxy solution.

Comment: @moonkotte Thanks for the input, I was able to install kube-state-metrics but I think we don't need kube-state-metrics when service discovery works in Prometheus. I need to find a grafana dashboard which will use kube-state-metrics and show pods mem usage, network. Is it possible with k8s-prometheus-proxy to get the metrics outside the cluster when Prometheus is not installed inside the kubernetes cluster with service discovery option?

Comment: Thanks @moonkotte, i was able to install prometheus and created grafana dashboards as well.