# Export kubernetes pods metrics to external prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have several k8s clusters and I would like to monitor pods metrics (cpu/memory mainly). For that, I already have one central instance of prometheus/grafana and I want to use it to monitor pods metrics from all my podsk8s clusters.

Sorry if the question was already asked by I already read lots of tutorials but it's always to install a dedicated prometheus/grafana instance on the cluster itself. I don't want that since I already have prometheus/grafana running somewhere else. I just want to "export" metrics.

I have metrics-servers installed on each clusters but I'm not sure if I need to deploy something else. Please advise me.

So, how can I export my pods metrics to my prometheus/grafana instance?

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/47643005/2777988

Answer (score 4):

Posting the answer as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

You need to use `federation` for prometheus for this purpose.

> Federation allows a Prometheus server to scrape selected time series
> from another Prometheus server.

Main idea of using `federation` is:

> Prometheus is a very flexible monitoring solution wherein each
> Prometheus server is able to act as a target for another Prometheus
> server in a highly-available, secure way. By configuring and using
> federation, Prometheus servers can scrape selected time series data
> from other Prometheus servers

See example [here](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/prometheus-federation/).